# check if crosswalk is running via javacode

Tags: java, cordova, crosswalk

I added some cordova plugin code that also contains an IntentService.

This service will be called regularly, even when the app is not running.

But crosswalkmethods like "new XWalkCookieManager().getCookie(url)" will crash ("this app has been closed" + crash in logcat). The instanciation `new XWalkCookieManager()` does work well but the `getCookie` crashes.

I already tried to debug it without success because you cannot attach the debugger to a closed app.

Is there an attribute or method in one of the XWalks classes/methods to check against that crosswalk is currently running or not?

Best would be something like this:

```
if(new XWalkCookieManager().isAvailable()) {
    //do stuff like getCookie
}
```

to prevent the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found a workaround to make sure that I execute crosswalk-methods only when the app is not killed. It is highly related to my use case so needs to be fitted to the requirements in another piece of code.

My use case is that, in a background location-event, I want to send HTTP requests. There I need to include the last used cookie of the crosswalk-app. I changed the app so that it always saves the crosswalk cookie in a `SharedPreferences` object (it calls my cordovaplugin and tells it `saveCookie()`, then the plugin gets it from crosswalk).

For reading the cookie, this is sufficient since I can read the cookie now from `SharedPreferences` at any time.

Now the problem is: When I recieve new cookies in the response, can I write them back to crosswalk? If the app is running, I would have to do `new XWalkCookieManager().setCookies()`. This will crash when executed in a killed app because crosswalk is not running when the locationupdate occures.

So my workaround for this is: I will save the cookie back to `SharedPreferences` first. Then I send a `Broadcast` to the `MainActivity` containing the cookie. I've also extended `MainActivity` (with cordova hook scripts) to contain a `BroadcastReciever` which then saves the cookie to crosswalk. The `MainActivity` is only running when the app is running. When the app is killed and therefore `MainActivity` is not running, nobody will recieve this `Broadcast` and there is no code to crash.

It is a huge workaround for a problem that should be solvable way more easy. But it seems there is no other way without a crosswalk that can tell if it is running or not (or just without crashing in those `getCookies()` etc methods).